# Acer Aspire One D270 fan continuously running

Tags: windows-7, acer-aspire-one, speedfan

I recently purchased a new Acer D270 netbook and observed that its fan is continuously running. Although fan was not making any audible noise at all i thought of using [Acer Aspire One Temperature Monitor and Fan Control](http://download.cnet.com/Acer-Aspire-One-Temperature-Monitor-and-Fan-Control/3000-2094_4-75280167.html) software even though it mentioned to use the software at your own risk I installed it on my netbook.

Now as soon as I ran it my fan speed increased 2 to 3 times the original speed. So, I uninstalled it and restarted my netbook. Now I am observing that even after uninstalling it my fan is running at a `faster speed(may be 1.5 times)` than when I had not installed it.

So, my question is why am I observing this behavior in fan speed and what can be done to reverse the effect of the software.

Comment: Did you have any luck in the end?

Comment: @James: I re-installed windows as I was going to try ubuntu also. So, now everything is working fine but nowdays I just use linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all computers are going to need at least one fan running all the time to avoid overheating so I would avoid using unproven applications like that one which could cause all sorts of problems.

- First, make sure you have a backup of anything important.
- I would suggest you try reinstalling the chipset driver from http://support.acer.com/product/default.aspx in case that program has modified anything.
- It may be worth accessing the BIOS to see if there are any options there for controlling fan speed. When you start up the netbook, it should tell you on screen which key you need to press to access the BIOS.
- If the fan is still not functioning normally you might want to try [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) to see if you can set the fan speed to normal levels.
- Lastly, if SpeedFan is unable to set fan speeds you could try updating the BIOS from the Acer support page in case the ACPI functionality has been improved. This should be a last resort as it could potentially mess up the computer.

Comment: I would just add/clarify that if the software made any changes in your BIOS (such as turning off automatic fan control in order to allow the software to handle this) then resetting your BIOS to defaults should return the fan operation back to normal.

Comment: I accessed the BIOS there are no setting for fan at all. I also tried speedfan and it is now showing any FAN at all when I click configure in it  because there is no default fan option there.

Comment: @BonGart: Are you talking abt the `load default` option in BIOS.?

Comment: @RanRag Yep.  When you got the netbook new, the settings in the BIOS were at the defaults.  So, choosing the 'load default" option in BIOS would return those settings to how it was, when it was new.  This won't affect Windows settings, but if that Fan software made any BIOS changes, loading the defaults will revert them back.

Comment: @BonGart: I tried that nothing happened. One more thing to install chipset driver is it necessary to first uninstall it or I can directly run the setup file I downloaded.

Comment: Probably best to uninstall existing driver first, although it is possible that you will lose some functionality until it is reinstalled, hence the reason why I suggested backing up anything important.

Comment: @RanRag the installer from Acer should be "smart" enough, where if it *needs* to uninstall the old drivers first, it would. (meaning the installation script would be written to detect them and uninstall them... if necessary)

Comment: @James: but how to uninstall it I have no idea. Where to look for the driver.?

Comment: @RanRag: You may be able to uninstall it from the "Programs and Features" applet in the Control Panel. But as Bon Gart said, you probably don't need to uninstall the existing driver as it should check for previous versions. I was just being cautious.

Comment: @James: I installed it by double-clicking it but my problem is still there and my fan is still running at a higher speed. So, I thought of manually uninstalling it. There is no entry of my chipset driver in `program and feature` section I believe it has to be removed from somewhere else which I have no idea of.

Comment: @RanRag: You could try using System Restore to restore the system to before you installed the fan control software. *Start-> Accessories -> System Tools -> System Restore*

Comment: @James: Nice suggestion. Will get back to you after system restore.

Comment: @James: Nothing happened. Now I have lost hope :(

Comment: @RanRag: Try powering the netbook down for a while to let it cool down. Then try to find out when the fan starts to speed up, i.e. whether it is straight away or only when you enter Windows. You could also try safe mode to see if there is any difference.

Comment: It could be worth trying System Repair, although it's doubtful that it would make a difference. If you open a command prompt as Administrator (see http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/) and type **sfc /scannow** it should check for damaged system files.